# Add Topics to a registry with Python API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iot

I need some help with the Google IoT Core API for Python...

For now I'm able to create and delete a registry as needed but, I need to also edit the registry to add more topics to it.

I researched a lot the documentation but no luck, maybe someone here have a similar issue or request? I need to be able to add Topics to a existent registry with active devices in it (no delete and re-creation possible?)

Any help is Greatly appretiated

EDIT: I found this reference: [Link to API Reference](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/reference/cloudiot/rest/v1/projects.locations.registries/patch?hl=es-419)

But I cant issue the command correctly :( a example could be usefull

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by topics?  Do you mean to change the PubSub topic associated with the registry for events?

Comment: Yes! there is 9 slots for topics (plus the default) on each register, I just want to add more topics associated to a existing register, for now i found if I use "patch(name=''regname", body=body)" i can get the registry to update but there seems some troubles with the command i cant seem to find out how to issue the command properly :(

Comment: Just to clarify I can create a registry with a given # of Pub/Sub topics but I need to edit this to add or delete such topics, my issue is with the "patch" function of the API I cant figure out how to issue the command correctly or even if is the proper way to do it to update the IoT Core Registry....

Answer (score 0):

You may use the google SDK to edit the registry and wrap the Shell command in a python script that format the topics, the proyect name, etc... the shell comand has this sctructure:

```
gcloud iot devices update {DEVICE_ID}
  --project={PROJECT_ID} 
  --region={REGION} 
  --registry={REGISTRY_ID}
```

For more information of the shell comand check the documentation:
[google registry docs](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/devices)